# Как загрузить на Github проект Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, github

У меня не получается добавить файлы через Share project в Android studio. 
Точнее, студия якобы это сделала, но не предложила файлы для загрузки на GitHub и, соответственно, ничего не загрузила. Притом, что репозиторий создался.

В чём может быть причина? Как загрузить весь проект?

Comment: А файлы в индекс добавлены? Т.е. они у вас красным или серым/зелёным/синим помечены в списке файлов?

Comment: Они никак не были помечены, я сделала, как было написано в одной статье, - Share project. И далее создался репозиторий на GitHub, а списка помеченных файлов не было. Но появилась надпись, что всё успешно загружено.

Comment: Откройте внизу в студии вкладку `VersionControl`->`LocalChanges` и посмотрите что там - там должен быть список добавленных/недобавленных в индекс файлов. Может у вас просто ничего не добавлено. Тогда самый простой спсоб - всё добавить. Ну и попробуйте закоммитить и запушить изменения. Можно так: `Ctrl+K` для коммита с последующим пушем или `Ctrl+Shift+K` для пуша, если уже всё закоммиченою